# Show that the rank of A is a non-decreasing function of time

Tags: matrices, tensor-products

I need to show that the rank of the matrix A defined as:

$A(t)=\int_0^{t} a(\tau)\otimes a(\tau) d\tau$

where: 
$a:\Re_{>0} \to \Re^n$

is a non-decreasing function of time... How should I start?

Comment: I tried to use one of the properties of the outer product, which says that the rank is always equal to 1...

Comment: So, since the argument of the definite integral is a matrix with rank=1, then the rank of $A(t)$ should be non-decreasing... But I don't know if the integral makes a difference... I mean, is there a way it might change the rank of the resulting matrix $A(t)$?

Comment: Yes, roughly speaking one is adding infinitesimal tensor squares of products, but those products are changing with time. Consider the case $a(\tau) = (1, \tau)$. As always, $A(0) = 0$, and so $\text{rank } A(0) = 0$, but $\det A(t) = \frac{1}{12} t^4$, so $\text{rank } A(t) = 2$ for $t > 0$.

Comment: So, how do I bridge the properties of the outer product with the matrix A(t)?

Comment: Infinitestimally $A$ is a "sum of tensor squares". I don't know the solution yet, but probably the eigenvalues (which are all real because $A(t)$ is symmetric) are all nondecreasing, so you might try to exploit that. It's a nice problem regardless.